# Combining many train_datagen in one using python and Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have multiple train_datagen (3) and I need to combine them in one and then fit the model using this resulting combined data generator but it doesn't works for me !!

```
train_datagen1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,rotation_range=15)

    train_generator1 = train_datagen1.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical', shuffle= True)

    train_datagen2 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,rotation_range=20)
    train_generator2 = train_datagen2.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical', shuffle= True)

    train_datagen3 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,rotation_range=30)
    train_generator3 = train_datagen3.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical', shuffle= True)

    trains_gene_tab=zip(train_generator1, train_generator2,train_generator3)

    history= model.fit_generator(
        trains_gene_tab,
        samples_per_epoch=120,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=50
        )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is there an error

Comment: when the program execute the history line, the model stop fitting at the beginning ie. epoch 1/100 and then show a large numpy array and done.